# Can't etablish connection with Owncloud and Docker

Tags: networking, server, docker, ip, owncloud-server

I created a cloud with owncloud run in docker. I download and extract this :

https://github.com/owncloud-docker/server

I open terminal in the folder and I type this :

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

So when I go to `127.0.0.1`, that works, when I go to `192.168.1.36` that works too.

I opened the ports `80` for `192.168.1.36` and I go by my public IP address, and firefox tell me :

> "Unable to connect"

So I try with Chrome and it say :

> xx.xxx.xx.xx refused to connect ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I try to change the addresses in the document `docker-compose.yml` but nothing changes.

*PS : I use Ubuntu 18.10 Desktop*

*PS2 : I already try to stop docker and to start again but nothing changes.*

Answer (score 2):

I finally read the [documentation](https://doc.owncloud.com/server/10.5/admin_manual/installation/docker/) where it clearly states the container was equipped to deal with port `8080` instead of `80`.

The issue was a result of the wrong ports being used. Instead of `80` try `8080`.